# How to stop python script in given time when calculation task takes long time?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I need to make sure my script runs exactly the given time - at the moment 1 minute.

Below is my program. The idea is to find suitable permutations that have the maximum calculated distance.
Script should end the job when time limit is exceeded. At the moment it does not. I think it is because inner calculations take longer time and checks won't happen.

I tried to put simple time function into loops but obviously it does not stop when needed.

Any help how to do it correctly?

```py
import time
import itertools
import multiprocessing

MAX_RUN_TIME = 60


def find_positions():
    no_of_elements = 3
    start_time = time.time()

    while True:
        positions = list(range(1, no_of_elements+1))
        all_permutations = list(itertools.permutations(positions, no_of_elements))

        if _check_time_limit(start_time, MAX_RUN_TIME):
            break

        results, distance = _calculate_distances(all_permutations, start_time)
        print(results)
        print(distance)

        no_of_elements += 1


def _calculate_distances(all_positions, start_time):
    max_distance = 0
    best_permutations = []
    num_processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_processes)

    results = pool.starmap(calculate_max_sum, [(pos, start_time) for pos in all_positions])

    for position, distance in zip(all_positions, results):
        if distance > max_distance:
            max_distance = distance
            best_permutations = [position]
        elif distance == max_distance:
            best_permutations.append(position)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    return best_permutations, max_distance


def calculate_max_sum(positions, start_time):
    sum_of_distances = 0
    previous = positions[0]

    for current in positions[1:]:
        sum_of_distances += abs(current - previous)
        previous = current

        if _check_time_limit(start_time, MAX_RUN_TIME):
            break

    return sum_of_distances


def _check_time_limit(start_time, limit):
    time_used = time.time() - start_time
    return time_used >= limit


find_positions()
```